# What type of View am I using in my MVC application?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am far from being an expert in the V area of MVC and have been experimenting with different  Views lately, the one I am currently trying out might not even be a proper View with a name, it's just something I came up with.

In my application a `Customer` can send a `Request` (Delivery request) to a `Courier`.
The `Request` has 4 states:

1. Sent
2. Cancelled
3. Rejected
4. Accepted

I have a `RequestView` which extends my `View`. I inject a `Request` entity into my `RequestView` on construction and depending on which state the `Request` is in the `RequestView` will choose the appropriate template.

My `RequestView` has some methods like:

```
protected function getStateText() {

    switch( $this->request->getState() ) {
    case Request::STATE_SENT:
        return 'Sent';
    case Request::STATE_CANCELLED:
        return 'Cancelled';
    case Request::STATE_REJECTED:
        return 'Rejected';
    case Request::STATE_ACCEPTED:
        return 'Accepted';
    default:
        return 'Error';
    }
}
```

Which I can then use in my templates by calling

```
echo $this->getStateText();
```

In the `Request` entity I only ever work with the state by using an INTEGER and when I am in the presentation layer nobody wants to see the state in number format they want to see the current state in text so that is why I have the `getStateText()` method in the presentation layer rather than in the entity itself. Is my thinking/reasoning correct here?

Is my current implementation good or bad? Does this type of View have a name?

Thanks.

Comment: I have never heard of that type of view having a specific name. So you have a View object with methods and then you extend that for a different kind of view? How is your view structured? I'm my experience the view is usually left to mostly HTML or other similar structure with minimal coding in place. The view template then receives variables that it can use. So I guess instead of extending your view to have a specific structure, you would send the view an object that would echo the getStateText() public function at the correct location. Depends, of course, on your whole MVC structure.

Comment: you might want to ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as this is not actually a specific programming problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why would `$this` within a template be pointing to a view? Then again, when I use word "template", I mean something like [this](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html).

Also, I am quite confused about reasons behind injection `Request` instance in the view. If view need data from model layer, it should just query it for said data. Then, if you have some shared visualization logic within that view, you can simply segregate it to an appropriate [presentation object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

Those presentation objects (Fowler calls them "presentation models", which I find to just add to the confusion) then can be used to produce values, that are ready to be applied to templates.

> <sub>And none of this has anything to do with MVVM. ViewModel is what you use in that pattern, when you swap out the Controller. This does not touch views in general. Also, the MVVM pattern is much closer to [MVP](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf) then anything else. It's what you would get, if you add MVP, a supervising controller, page controller and then let someone, who worships Rails, to shake it all up.</sub>

As for the naming what you currently have, unfortunately I would simply label it *"an [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violation"* and keep poking at it.

<kbd>my 2 cents</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

**Does this type of View have a name?**

You are venturing towards MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel).

**Is my current implementation good or bad?**

Based on what you've shown, I think you are heading in the right direction as far as separation of concerns so I'd say you're doing good.

One thing I would do is tuck away the `getStateText` logic in another class (e.g. `RequestStateToTextTransformer` => `transform` and `reverseTransform` methods).

Why? Well, perhaps you want to display the Request entity elsewhere and in a different format. You would currently have to duplicate `getStateText` code in a different ViewModel. With a transformer, there's no duplication.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about how to stop code duplication and I never heard of these transformers. Do you have any good links explaining them further?

Comment: The example I was thinking of is Symfony2 data transformers. Take a look at an example on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#creating-the-transformer